# No se muestran las texturas en OpenGL

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl

tengo un problema. Estoy usando Xcode y OpenGL para un proyecto de graficación.

Me encuentro con el siguiente problema: Las imágenes no son mostradas en la pantalla. Sólo se dibuja el cuadro donde deseo colocar la textura.
Mi código es el siguiente:

Header: Image.hpp

```
#ifndef IMAGEN_HPP_INCLUDED
#define IMAGEN_HPP_INCLUDED

// Especificacion de Image que nos ayudara a cargar y mostrar las imagenes
class Image
{
private:
   unsigned char* Data;
   int ancho;
    int alto;

 public:

// Constructor con parametros de Ancho y Alto que son de la imagen real y
// la direccion de la imagen
Image(int iw, int ih, const char* path)
{
    this->ancho = iw;
    this->alto = ih;

    CargarImagen(path);
}

// Funcion para cargar una imagen en memoria
int CargarImagen(const char* path)
{
    FILE *imagen = fopen(path, "r");
    int InfoTam = this->ancho * this->alto * 3;
    this->Data = (unsigned char*) malloc( InfoTam );

    if( imagen == NULL ){
        cout<<"ERROR"<<endl;
        return 0; }
    else{
        cout<<"Imagen cargada"<<endl;
    }

    fread(this->Data, InfoTam, 1, imagen);

    fclose(imagen);
    return 1;
}

// Dibujar la imagen que esta en memoria
void Dibujar(int x, int y, int w, int h)
{
    glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, this->ancho, this->alto, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Data);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(x, y);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 1.0); glVertex2f(x + w, y);
        glTexCoord2f(1.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(x + w, y + h);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0); glVertex2f(x, y + h);
    glEnd();
}
};

#endif
```

Y este es el bloque el archivo main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GLUT/GLUT.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h> //New
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

#include "image.hpp"

#define pi 3.1415962
int ancho=700, alto=700;
float cx, cy=70; //Posición inicial. Donde empieza a caer la basura
int xpos, ypos, caida=1; //Posicion del mouse

int puntaje=0;

//Declaracion de imagenes
Image* BotePapel = new 
Image(256,256,"/Users/luissegovia/Documents/Recycle.raw");
Image* Fondo = new 
Image(2048,2048,"/Users/luissegovia/Documents/Background.raw");


//Funcion de display
void CodeFun(){
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   //Limpia Buffer
glPointSize(100);               //Tamaño del punto

//----------
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
BotePapel->Dibujar(3, 1, 10, 10);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
//Fondo->Dibujar(0, 0, 700, 700);

//

glFlush();
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
//Parametros de inicio de OpenGL

glutInit(&argc,argv); //Inicializar libreria Glut
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB); //Establece modo de 
visualizacion incial

glutInitWindowSize(ancho,alto); //Tamanio de ventana
glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);    //Posicion de la ventana
glutCreateWindow("Prototipo Juego 2D"); //Titulo de ventana
glClearColor(1,0.5,0.5,1);      //Color de fondo
gluOrtho2D(0,70,0,70);//Inicializacion del plano (1er cuadrante)

glutDisplayFunc(CodeFun);

glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

Sólo se dibuja el cuadro blanco. ¿A qué se deberá?
Muchas gracias por su ayuda de antemano. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder asociar la imagen a la textura (función glTexImage2D) debes haber creado un objeto textura con la instrucción glGenTexture, y luego indicar que quieres operar con ese objeto texture glBindTexture:

```
GLint texture[1];
glGenTextures(1, &texture[0]);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, this->ancho, this->alto, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, Data);
```

La creación del objeto textura y la asignación de la textura, debes hacerlo una vez, de lo contrario estarás creando texturas en la tarjeta gráfica hasta dejarla sin memoria.

La opción más lógica es hacerlo en el main después de haber creado la ventana OpenGL (glutCreateWindow).